# Get weekday of arbitrary date with applescript

Tags: applescript

I'm working on a script to create a table of contents.  The format for each item of this toc is: weekday, month day. Example: Sunday, September 1.  I have a date in the format of "09/01/2018".  Can I use this date to get the weekday? When I try the following I get the error "BBEdit got an error: Can’t get weekday of date "09/01/2018"."

```
set theDate to theMonth & "/" & theDay & "/" & theYear --> "09/01/2018"
set theWeekday to (weekday of date theDate)
```

I'v also tried setting theDate "as date" to which it says "Can’t make "09/01/2018" into type date." And I've also tried adding "tell application "{BBEdit, Finder, System Events}" to set theDate..." and each one gave the same same error as above.

The only info I can seem to find when googling is how to get currentDate or some other date based on whatever "today" is. Nothing for just a random date, which is what I need.

I'm sure I'm just missing something pretty simple here, but I'm pretty new to AppleScript so any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most reliable (and locale independent) way is to create the date with `current date` and set the properties

```
set theMonth to 8
set theDay to 14
set theYear to 2018

set currentDate to current date
-- the first `day` avoids an overflow error 
tell currentDate to set {day, year, its month, day} to {1, theYear, theMonth, theDay}
set theWeekday to weekday of currentDate
```

or with a litte help from Cocoa

```
use framework "Foundation"

set dateComponents to current application's NSDateComponents's alloc()'s init()
dateComponents's setYear:theYear
dateComponents's setMonth:theMonth
dateComponents's setDay:theDay
set theDate to (current application's NSCalendar's currentCalendar()'s dateFromComponents:dateComponents) as date
set theWeekday to weekday of theDate
```

Comment: @user3439894 First of all you have to set the first `day` to `1`, my bad. Try the code without setting the first `day` with a current date for example `January, 31` and a new date `February, 14`. Without setting the day to a value which is valid in all months an overflow occurs and you'll get `March, 14` because there is no day 31 in February.

Comment: You don't get an error per se, you'll get a wrong date. This occurs on each 31st when the destination month has 30 days. For a reliable behavior you have to set the `day` component to a *valid* value **before** setting the month.

Comment: Okay, that makes sense now. Thanks! +1